# Shrink wrap with movement

Tags: animation, shrinkwrap

as the title says I’m wondering how to get my shrink wrapped logo to stay on object while it moves. When I start animation, the shrink wrap stays in place. How do I fix this?

Comment: Assuming you've used Import as Planes to import your logo, have you parented it to your main object?

Comment: I have attempted to parent but it still doesn't want to stay on object for some reason. Its clothing, if you think that may have something to do with it. I press on clothing and shrink wrapped logo, right click and press parent. Am I missing steps?

Comment: pls provide blend file so we can see what you did and correct it. thx

Comment: If the logo is parented to the clothng _Object_ , only the relative transforms of the _objects_ will be maintained. The deformations will not necessarily be followed. A UV texture would be better? Anyway,as Chris has suggested, go ahead and share a representative sample of your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Jeremy Do it the other way round. - Select the logo then Shift-select the object, Ctrl-P > Parent > Object (Keep transform).

Comment: @RobinBetts Having trouble compressing file in order to share file. 300MB but only allows 30 MB. Have tried compressing files in settings